# What is MAUI Blazor for?

Tags: c#, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

The question is fairly self-explanatory I think.

MAUI is the evolution of Xamarin.Forms, a cross-platform UI framework.

Blazor is MS' new front-end C# framework.

MAUI Blazor, however, I'm unclear of.

I suspect it is one of the following:

- Essentially a web-view wrapper for Blazor, similar to how Electron works.
- Allows you to target MAUI apps for web (I thought you could do this anyway but I could be wrong)
- Allows you to target Blazor apps to native

So what exactly are hybrid maui/blazor apps for? What do they let you do that you couldn't do with just MAUI or just Blazor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on which technology you want to write the UI in, and how you want the user to run your app.

|  | UI written in HTML / CSS | UI written in XAML |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Native App | Blazor MAUI | MAUI |
| Browser Website | Blazor (+Razor and regular ASP.Net) | Doesn't exist |

> Essentially a web-view wrapper for Blazor, similar to how Electron works.

Is correct. You can either manually create a [BlazorWebView control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/blazorwebview) or use the Maui Blazor template which will scafold all that for you.

> Allows you to target MAUI apps for web

Is incorrect. This doesn't let you run XAML UI in the browser.

> Allows you to target Blazor apps to native

Is mostly right. You can re-use the same Blazor components and logic in your Maui Blazor application, so you can have (mostly) the same code base and user experience across the browser and native apps.